# Update no PlayFramework não funcionando

Tags: java, play-framework

estou testando o play-framework 2.4.3 e fiz o codigo abaixo para atualizar o modelo que recebo via json, mas somente o update não esta funcionando. Estou com o log das consultas habilitadas mas apenas aparece um select para essa action. Estou usando o banco H2. O que esta faltando ?

```
//Imports do controller    
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.libs.*;
import views.html.*;
import java.util.*;
import models.*;

//Código da action
Estado estadoParametro = Json.fromJson(request().body().asJson(), Estado.class);
Estado estado = Estado.find.byId(id);       
estado.nome = estadoParametro.nome;
estado.update();
```

Comment: Estranho, pois teoricamente era para funcionar. Nesse caso tem que analisar tudo, tipo seu Model Estado, verificar se o id que esta realmente existe. Faça um teste simples na mão mesmo, tipo:
Estado estado = Estado.find.byId(1); //Deve ser um id existente
estado.nome = "Qualquer coisa";
estado.update();

Depois verifique se sofreu alteração

Comment: Resolvi esse problema criando um novo projeto e movendo os controllers e modelos para o novo projeto. Parou de dar problema. Estranho.